# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in People#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to make a table that has sortable columns. I used the railscast #228 as a reference but I'm getting the title error when I try to run my code. It's probably because I'm calling the wrong method. Here is my code and error message for your reference. 
 [image]

[image]
[image]

Let me know if you need any other code. Thank You!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, copy and paste your actual code.

Comment: Please, whenever possible copy and paste actual code and do not use screenshots. These are really difficult to work with because people must retype your examples.

Comment: Thanks! will do. I'm still new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `sort_column` method: replace `"phone number"` with `"phone_number"`. Notice the `_` character.

Comment: Thanks for the help!